# Template size multidimensional arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I would like to use template to specify sizes in functions. Let me give you an example.
I can do this:

```
int sub (int a[2][2]) {

}
int main () {
   int a[2][2];
   sub(a);
}
```

I can do this:

```
template<int size2>
int sub (int a[][size2]) {

}
int main () {
   int a[2][2];
   sub(a);
}
```

But what I would like is this:

```
template<int size1, int size2>
int sub (int a[size1][size2]) {

}
int main () {
   int a[2][2];
   sub(a);
}
```

How could I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The better option is probably to use `std::array`, if you have C++11 support, or `std::vector`, if not. If you really want to use C-style arrays, you can *pass them by reference*, using the following syntax.

```
template<size_t size1, size_t size2>
int sub (int (&a)[size1][size2]) {
    // ...
}
int main() {
    int a[2][2];
    sub(a);
}
```

Comment: I am really intrigued that this seems to work (only tried it in MSVC so far). Could you elaborate on why the compiler is able to deduce both template arguments when passing by reference, but not when being passed by value?

Comment: Well, you can't pass an array by value, but, yeah, when you pass an array but not as a reference, it decays into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @BrianBi but how compiler deduces size?

Comment: @piotruś well, when you pass an array by reference, it *doesn't* decay, and you *have* to pass it an array of the correct size; otherwise the reference binding will fail. That's how the compiler can deduce the size.

Comment: what do you mean by correct size? you can pass any 2d array. also can you please correct grammar above?

Comment: @piotruś the point is that `sub(a)` only makes sense if `size1` and `size2` are both 2. Therefore, the compiler deduces that they *must* be 2. On the other hand, without the reference, `size1` could not be deduced because `int a[size1][size2]` as a function parameter is identical to `int (*a)[size2]`.

Comment: you can write: int a[2][3]; sub(a); question is: how does compiler deduce that size1=2 and size2=3?

Comment: @piotruś Because the compiler knows that `a` is an array of size 2x3. What exactly is confusing?

Comment: I see, confusing is how does he just know this? but this is a homework to do myself, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Bi already wrote, the best way to go is to use `std::array`.

But to answer your question, it is halfway possible to do what you want.

When you use a C-style 2D array as an argument to a function, it decays to a pointer to an array of the second dimension. For example `int a[6][6]` decays to `int (*a)[6]`, so the first dimension is hidden and means nothing to the compiler. The second dimension however, can be used as template parameters and can be deduced.

For example:

```
template<int S>
void func(int (*a)[S])
{
    cout << S << endl;
}
```

and then:

```
int a[66][67];
func(a);
```

prints "67".

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way (sub<2,2>:

```
template<int size1, int size2>
int sub (int a[size1][size2]) {

}    
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a[2][2];
    sub<2,2>(a);
}
```